# Unity3d android считать настройку автоповорота экрана

Tags: android, unity3d, unity3d-android

Как в Unity в приложении под android считать текущую настройку автоповорота экрана, которую задал пользователь в настройках телефона?

Мое приложение умеет работать в разной ориентации экрана, но почему-то всегда реагирует на поворот экрана. Мне же нужно, чтобы приложение реагировало на поворот только если пользователь включил (разрешил) в телефоне "Автоповорот", если же запретил - то приложение не должно реагировать на поворот.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [тут](https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-auto-rotation-when-locked.280342/) есть возможное решение.

```
void OnApplicationFocus(bool haveFocus)
{
    if (haveFocus) GameScreen.ToggleAutoRotation();
}

static void ToggleAutoRotation()
{
    AutoRotationOn = DeviceAutoRotationIsOn();
    Screen.autorotateToPortrait = AutoRotationOn;
    Screen.autorotateToPortraitUpsideDown = AutoRotationOn;
    Screen.autorotateToLandscapeLeft = AutoRotationOn;
    Screen.autorotateToLandscapeRight = AutoRotationOn;
    Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.AutoRotation;
}

static bool DeviceAutoRotationIsOn()
{
    #if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
    using (var actClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
    {
        var context = actClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        AndroidJavaClass systemGlobal = new AndroidJavaClass("android.provider.Settings$System");
        var rotationOn = systemGlobal.CallStatic<int>("getInt", context.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getContentResolver"), "accelerometer_rotation");

        return rotationOn==1;
    }
    #endif
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Немного поправил, работает отлично, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю сюда доработанный вариант, а то предложенный в ответе не компилировался.

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace MyUtils
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// На Android текущая настройка автоповорота экрана, которую задал пользователь в настройках телефона, почему-то игнорируется Unity.
    /// Подпора данной ситуации находится в этом классе.
    /// https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1086526/unity3d-android-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0/1086532#1086532
    /// </summary>
    public class FixAndroidScreenAutoRotationScript : MonoBehaviour
    {
        /* Если надо все то же самое на нескольких сценах, то можно сделать примерно так здесь или в классе-контейнере:
        private FixAndroidScreenAutoRotationScript instance;
        private void Start()
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = this;
                DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
            }
            else
                Destroy(gameObject);
        }*/

        private void OnApplicationFocus(bool haveFocus)
        {
            if (haveFocus)
            {
                bool autoRotation = SetAutoRotation();
                Debug.Log(nameof(OnApplicationFocus) + ": " + nameof(autoRotation) + "=" + autoRotation.ToString());
            }
        }

        private static bool SetAutoRotation()
        {
            bool autoRotation = GetDeviceAutoRotation();
            Screen.autorotateToPortrait = autoRotation;
            Screen.autorotateToPortraitUpsideDown = autoRotation;
            Screen.autorotateToLandscapeLeft = autoRotation;
            Screen.autorotateToLandscapeRight = autoRotation;
            Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.AutoRotation;
            return autoRotation;
        }

        private static bool GetDeviceAutoRotation()
        {
#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
            using (var actClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
            {
                var context = actClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
                AndroidJavaClass systemGlobal = new AndroidJavaClass("android.provider.Settings$System");
                var rotationOn = systemGlobal.CallStatic<int>("getInt", context.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getContentResolver"), "accelerometer_rotation");

                return rotationOn == 1;
            }
#else
            return true;
#endif
        }
    }
}
```